# CTRL + hover doesn't show definition for my vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I write a VSCode extension to support a new language. It uses registerDefinitionProvider() to register a definition provider. And it works when pressing F12, ctrl + click the symbol, or right-clicks and choosing the "Go to Definition".
But VSCode shows nothing when I use ctrl + hover on the symbol since VSCode 1.67. It works well before 1.67.

It shows nothing since VSCode 1.67

[image: img1]

It works well if the VSCode version lower than 1.67

[image: img2]

The ts code:

```
context.subscriptions.push(vscode.languages.registerDefinitionProvider(['test'], {provideDefinition(doc, position, token) {
        var word = doc.getText(doc.getWordRangeAtPosition(position));
        var rst:vscode.Location[]|undefined = macroManager.getPositionByMacro(word);
        return rst;
    }}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know how to fix this.

```
constructor Location(uri: Uri, rangeOrPosition: vscode.Range | vscode.Position): vscode.Location
```

The second parameter of the Location constructor can be Range or Position. `Ctrl`+ hover shows nothing if it's a Position.

So the code should be:

```
let range_begin = new vscode.Position(lineNum, 0);
let range_end = new vscode.Position(endLineNum, 0);
let position_range = new vscode.Range(range_begin, range_end);
positionLink.push(new vscode.Location(value.resourceUri, position_range));
```

Answer (score 0):

check your extensions. it happens when the VS Code built in extensions are disabled.
search @builtin  in the extensions search bar and make sure every extension is enabled